# usage of mprotect() on array

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to allocate an array of integers and then map the pages to two different static heaps using *mmap()* and then protect one of the heaps using *mprotect()* with protection PROT_NONE.
It seems like that mprotect() is protecting a lot more than the heap that I told it to do

```
int main(){

//shared data 
int    *p_array;
struct sigaction sa;
int i=0;

p_array = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*NUM_ELEMENTS);      // allocate 100 ints
size_t size_of_p_array = sizeof(p_array);

//SIGSEGV Handler initialization
sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
sa.sa_sigaction = handler;
if (sigaction(SIGSEGV, &sa, NULL) == -1)
    handle_error("sigaction");

    protected_Heap = mmap (p_array, size_of_p_array, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);   /* anonymous mapping doesn't need a file desc */
    nonprotected_Heap = mmap (p_array, size_of_p_array, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);   /* anonymous mapping doesn't need a file desc */  

    //write to the page to obtain a private copy
    for (i=0; i<NUM_ELEMENTS;i++){
        protected_Heap[i]=i;
        nonprotected_Heap[i]=i;
    }

    // Make the memory unwritable
    mprotect(protected_Heap,sizeof(int)*NUM_ELEMENTS, PROT_NONE);

    printf("will write and it should not trigger an Access violation\n");
    nonprotected_Heap[3] =0; // Should not trigger the SIGSEGV
    protected_Heap[NUM_ELEMENTS+2]=0; //Should not trigger signal but it does
    printf("will write and it should trigger an Access Violation\n");
    protected_Heap[3] =0; // Should trigger the SIGSEGV

     //Unmap the memory
     munmap (protected_Heap,size_of_p_array);
     munmap (nonprotected_Heap,size_of_p_array);
     return 0;
}
```

Is there any way to just protect until the end of the array and not any further?

Comment: 1) Do not cast the result of `malloc` & friends or `void *` in general in C! 2) Format & indent that mess!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mprotect` granularity is limited and it will always protect full pages. As the size of page is 4kB on x86, it's not possible to protect 100 int array.

Secondly, current `mmap` is a bit weird as you can't mmap to address which is already occupied in the process. Pass NULL and allocate completely new memory which will later free by calling `munmap`.

Last but not least - to achieve the above, you can allocate full page and then adjust the array pointer so the end points to the end of the page.